# Navbar transition in tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, navbar, tailwind-css

I have a navbar and I want that when someone clicks on the button, it will be open with `transition` in [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/).

```js
const bar_btn = document.getElementById('BAR-BTN');
const mobileMenu = document.getElementById('mobileMenu')
bar_btn.addEventListener(
 'click',
  function() {
    mobileMenu.classList.toggle('w-0')
    mobileMenu.classList.toggle('h-0')
  }
)
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <button id='BAR-BTN'><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i></button>
  </div>
  <ul class="transition-transform ease-linear h-0 w-0 delay-1000 duration-1000"
    id="mobileMenu">
    <li>test-1</li>
    <li>test-2</li>
    <li>test-3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my HTML and javascript code and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find a way to give transition to height property(which we can in pure css) so i used scale to give a transition effect

See if it helps

```js
  const bar_btn = document.getElementById('BAR_BTN');
  const mobileMenu = document.getElementById('mobileMenu')

  bar_btn.addEventListener('click',function()
   {
          mobileMenu.classList.toggle('transform');

      }
  );
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <div>
    <button id="BAR_BTN" class="px-10 py-2 mt-10 mx-10 w-1/4 hover:bg-green-300 bg-green-200 transition-all">button</button>
  </div>
  <ul id="mobileMenu" class="mx-10 p-5 border-4 border-black overflow-hidden text-xl w-1/4 origin-top  duration-300 scale-y-0" >
    <li>Test-1</li>
    <li>Test-2</li>
    <li>Test-3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem just now and I solve it.

```
// .tsx


navigationRef.current?.classList.toggle('active');

<div ref={navigationRef} className=' w-[80px] ... duration-500 transition-all ' />
```

```
// index.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .active {
    width: 300px !important;
  }
}
```

The effect as follow:

[image]

No need scale and the effect may be not as expected.